# I used the cookie to prevent losing card data, but when I refresh the page, I lose the card value. How can I solve this problem?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

In the Mycards.js component I'm adding `item` to the card with button:

Mycards.js component:

```
export default function MediaCard() {
  const context = useContext(AppContext);

  const addToCard = (item) => {
    const newCard = {
      pic: item.itemMainPic,
      des: item.itemName,
      price: item.rangePriceFormat,
      score: item.score,
      id: context.count,
      explink: item.itemUrl,
    };

    context.setcount(context.count + 1);

    context.setcard((prev) => [...prev, newCard]);
  };



  return (
    <div>
      <ul>
        <Container>
          <Grid
            container
            spacing={1}
            justifyContent="center"
            alignItems="center"
          >
            {Myjson.map((item) => {
              return (
                <Grid item key={item.itemId}>
                  <Button
                    value={item.itemMainPic}
                    sx={{ width: 308 }}
                    variant="contained"
                    endIcon={<AddShoppingCartIcon />}
                    onClick={(e) => {
                      addToCard(item);
                    }}
                  >
                    add to card
                  </Button>
                </Grid>
              );
            })}
          </Grid>
        </Container>
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}
```

So when I refresh the page whatever was inside the card is gone.

In the _app.js file I set a cookie which stores the card:  `setCookie('key', JSON.stringify(card), { path: '/', maxAge: 60 * 60 * 24 });`

_app.js file:

```
import Layout from '../components/layout';
import { useState, createContext, useEffect } from 'react';
import AppContext from '../components/AppContext';
import '../styles/globals.css';
import { getCookies, getCookie, setCookie, deleteCookie } from 'cookies-next';

export default function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  const [count, setcount] = useState(0);
  const [card, setcard] = useState([]);
  const [cartp, setcartp] = useState('');
  setCookie('key', JSON.stringify(card), { path: '/', maxAge: 60 * 60 * 24 });

  return (
    <div>
      <AppContext.Provider
        value={{
          count,
          setcount,
          card,
          setcard,

          cartp,
          setcartp,
        }}
      >
        <Layout>
          <Component {...pageProps} />
        </Layout>
      </AppContext.Provider>
    </div>
  );
}
```

When I refresh the page, I use dev tools, and I see my cookie, and the value is `%5B%5D`, which means `[]` and then I click on the button, and the value changes; for example, it becomes this:

```
%5B%7B%22pic%22%3A%22https%3A%2F%2Faaa.jpg%22%2C%22des%22%3A%22aaa%22%2C%22price%22%3A%22aaa%22%2C%22score%22%3A%22aaa%22%2C%22id%22%3A0%2C%22explink%22%3A%22aaa%22%7D%5D
```

Which means:

```
[{"pic":"https://aaa.jpg","des":"aaa","price":"aaa","score":"aaa","id":0,"explink":"aaa"}]
```

But when I refresh the page, the value is now `%5B%5D`

I used the cookie to prevent losing card data, but when I refresh the page, I lose the card value. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: You are setting empty array to the cart. First `card` is `[]` - `const [card, setcard] = useState([]);` then you call `JSON.stringify(card)`. You never read the cookie

Comment: @Konrad I thought I could read the cookie with `setcard(getCookie('key')` but it just confused me and didn't work. How can I read the cookie?

Comment: `const [card, setcard] = useState(() => JSON.parse(getCookie('key')) || []);` would make more sense. You can't use `setCard`, because the cookie is alreasy overwritten by your `setCookie`

Comment: @Konrad
When I use your code I get `SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0`
I tried `const [card, setcard] = useState(() => getCookie('key') || []);` and it worked but the value looks like this `"\"[\\\"\\\\\\\"\\\",\\\"[\\\",\\\"]\\\",\\\"\\\\\\\"\\\",{\\\"pic`

Comment: I used `eval` instead of `JSON.parse` :`eval(getCookie('key') || [])` and it worked.
But I'm not sure if it's secure to use `eval` instead of `JSON.parse`